# Cannot update built-in apps on a brand new macbook

Tags: mac-appstore

I received a brand new macbook pro a few days ago. I have logged in to the app store with my own Apple ID but I am unable to update the built-in applications: Pages, Numbers, Keynote etc.

The error is:

> This update is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled.

I have done a bit of research about this, but these apps *came* with my machine. It's not possible they were purchased with another Apple ID as this came straight from ordering online at Apple.com and came in a sealed box.

Comment: Have you tried deleting those applications all together (keeping a backup in case of problems) and then reinstalling from the App Store?

Comment: Your best bet is to contact Apple directly.  They can investigate and resolve the problem in the quickest manner.

Comment: sometimes when you log in from new device it does that. Go to your profile (in App Store) and verify the device (Mac) is correctly showing

Comment: @Buscar웃 As soon as I went to the account tab it asked to bundle these apps to my apple ID. Thank you this was my solution. I'm not able to mark this as answered as this was not an "answer".

Comment: OK, I'll make this an answer so you can mark it as done, and others can find the simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when you log in with new device the App Store gets bit confused.

Go to you Account in App Store and verify it showing the right device.

Comment: In Mojave's App Store, where do you see your device in your account?

Comment: @Redarm I do not know, do not have Mojave, but on High Sierra go to your account and click Edit

Comment: Do you mean "Edit at appleid.apple.com"?  Which then forwards you to appleid.apple.com in a browser?

Comment: @Redarm you go it, do you have that problem

Comment: No, not yet anyway.  I was just curious where the device is meant to be displayed.  Thanks.

Comment: @Redarm You simply click your name and icon in the bottom left of the app store. There will be a message waiting for you to claim your apps.